# Converting Access 2000 to Access 365

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to convert Access 2000 32 bit to Access 365 64 bit. I tried holding the shift key of the .mdb application and opened .mdb file in access 2000. I can see all the queries, tables, modules and forms. When I tried to export the modules and forms, the export button is disabled. The export button is only enabled for tables. Below is the screen shot of modules, forms and tables:

[image]

[image]

for tables, the export is enabled:

[image]

I could not figure how to export in office 2000 so I tried to open the Access .mdb file in office 365 by holding the shift key, but here, I opened the access file, but could not even see the save as option so I tried to open the same Access 2000 file in Access 2013. I tried to open the .mdb file by holding the shift key and it opened the database showing all the forms, tables and modules. I created an empty database and tried to import forms, modules and tables in this empty database. I successfully imported the tables, but I could not import the forms and modules. The forms and modules tab was disabled just like office 2000. Below are the screen shots of modules and forms that is disabled.

[image]

[image]

Below is the screen shot of tables that is highlighted.

[image]

I then tried to save the .mdb file to save as .accdb format by trying the save as option, but when I tried the save as option, I go an error. Below is the screen shot of the error:

[image]

I have been trying to convert this .mdb database to access 365 for past two days and I cannot go beyond importing the tables. I want everything to be imported to access 365. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Please let me know if anyone needs any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a *replication design master*.

You may have to remove the replication before conversion, as this is not supported from Access 2007 and onwards.

There is a tool by *Michael Kaplan* for this:

[TSI Access 2000 Un-Replicator](http://www.trigeminal.com/lang/1033/utility.asp?ItemID=7#7)

Comment: what is a replication design master? This is the original .mdb database. I didn't replicate it or it is not a copy

Comment: The name indicates that, and the table icons have small marks. And this is where Bing/Google comes in: _What is database replication in Microsoft Access_

Comment: I un-replicated the database, but I lost all the forms, modules, only tables got unreplicated.